# how to logged one web browser out if you are logged in to another web browser?

Tags: php

How can you automatically logged out one browser if you want to log in to another browser of the same page?

I am having an evaluation form. And the problem starts here: if you evaluate from the other form and submit its values.

On the other browser, you also evaluate and submit values.

Both values from the two browser submit values which is wrong. If that browser submits values, the other browser must not submit its own value because values from another page is already submitted.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaand..... nope. Lost you. Please try to explain better, or have someone who speaks English better explain the problem.

Comment: if you are posting the value to a db, check first in the db  if values are already there..
and to take care of multiple logins, you have to go the same way of checking a value in the db if the user is already logged in...
why they made http stateless??

Answer (score 1):

If you use a database, you can store a session parameter upon logging in in the database and validate the session when a form is submitted. If you have not logged in somewhere else, the session will still be valid, otherwise the session won't match.